# Join a 'default' value only when there is no fully matching record

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to be able to join to a 'default' row in a table (righttable) *only* when there is no matching record for both fields in lefttable.  Below is the raw contents of the tables

```
#lefttable
--------------------
value  program  race
100    gold     1
100    gold     4
100    gold     5


#righttable
-------------------------
commission  program  race
14          GOLD     1
23          GOLD     NULL
```

In this example, where the race is 1 I need to pick the first row (commission = 14) but if the race is anything other than 1 I need to pick the NULL row that matches the other field (commission = 23)

The problem I'm having is that my query picks the null record **and** the matching record when joining,  resulting in duplication...

```
SELECT #lefttable.race,
       totalvalue = SUM(value),
       commission = SUM(value * (commission * 0.01))
  FROM #lefttable
  LEFT JOIN #righttable  ON #lefttable.program = #righttable.program
                        AND #lefttable.race = ISNULL(#righttable.race, #lefttable.race)
 GROUP BY #lefttable.race;
```

This results in the below

```
--------------------
race  totalvalue  commission
1     200         37.00
3     100         23.00
4     100         23.00
```

The totalvalue is double what it should be (and commission incorrect) because the join has created two rows for race 1 (one for each row in righttable)

Ideally I want to be able to solve this problem entirely within the join clause rather than having to add messy cludges to the select clause, or additional joins, or views, or modify righttable to create a row for each race regardless.

I have tried different ways of constructing the join clause but I can't quite wrap my head around how to say "Give me the row with the null race only if there is no row that matches the race in lefttable" using a sql join.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 for an interesting question (it had me stumped - but I like McNets' solution), but I'm also giving out to you! You have > 500 points here (and more points on StackExchange, Super User and Server Fault so you **should** know that images are frowned upon here for reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). In future, for your database questions, please provide DDL and DML as formatted text, or better still in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I was in a hurry to get the question posted and using images seemed like the quickest way.  I will read that link when I get a chance, and figure out how to do it properly (perhaps by editing my question)

Comment: To be fair it's images of code that's frowned upon. I posted images of the data, not the code, because I didn't know how to format it in a table when pasting in.   I will figure it out.

Comment: And if one wishes to create a fiddle with that data? You have to go back and forth between your image and the fiddle itself. With the data as text, the person trying to help can copy and paste it at the bottom of a text field and then do `CREATE TABLE foo (...` and then just look down or Del the fields into position - less likelihood of errors creeping in. Or to copy and paste it into MySQL Workbench for example? Indeed, the first point in the accepted answer (556 upvotes) says `Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor` - so it's **both** code **and** data! :-)

Comment: @Vérace, ok I understand.   Have replaced my data images with tables.

Comment: i'm not trying to get at you, I'm really not :-), but having it as DDL and DML which can be directly copied and pasted as working code rather than as raw data would be **even better**! Best of all is as a fiddle as mentioned above (with code included in question also) - just hit run! :-) There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to have a look? `Have replaced my data images with tables` - Fair play to you for doing it anyway even though you've already accepted the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it by using an OUTER APPLY join plus TOP 1

```
select
    *
from 
    righttable r 
where 
    (r.race=1 and r.program = 'gold')
    or
    r.race is null
order by
    case when r.race is null then 1 else 0 end
```

returns:

```
commission | program | race
---------: | :------ | ---:
        14 | gold    |    1
        23 | gold    | null
```

but you just need the first row, that you can get by using a TOP 1 in this way:

```
select
    l.race, 
    totalvalue = sum(value), 
    commission = SUM(value * (commission * 0.01))
from 
    lefttable l
outer apply
    (select top 1 
        commission 
     from 
         righttable r 
     where 
         (r.race=l.race and r.program = l.program)
         or
         r.race is null
     order by
         case when r.race is null then 1 else 0 end) r
group by
    l.race;
```

```
race | totalvalue | commission
---: | ---------: | :---------
   1 |        100 | 14.00     
   4 |        100 | 23.00     
   5 |        100 | 23.00
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e101317385d1fe06b012d2bb598544da)*

Comment: Thankyou!  That worked in my test data, and I can see how to make it work in my real-world situation.

Comment: I'm glad to help.